# how to get the input of the deep learning model

Tags: deep-learning, transformer-model

I trained a transformer encoder model with 10 dimensional inputs and 300 dimensional outputs. How can I backtrack to get this 10 dimensional input now that I have a new output? My current idea is to use mcmc but it's too slow, does anyone have a more efficient method?

Comment: Do you mean you basically want to invert the transformer? Given some output, what input would have produced that output?

Comment: @cadolphs yes you are right